# Python change data in the list with post method

Tags: python, post

I am doing Python Backend. Maybe more practising than doing, but I have been struggling now with problem I hope you can help me.

List:

```
works = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'Car washing', 'status': 'undone', 'worker': ''},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'Car waxing', 'status': 'done', 'worker': ''}
]
```

I want change job id 1 status undone to done. So after modification list look like this:

```
works = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'Car washing', 'status': 'done', 'worker': ''},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'Car waxing', 'status': 'done', 'worker': ''}
]
```

This is what I have done, not working:

```
@app.post('/works/{id}')
def change_status(id: int, status: Optional[str] = None):
    wks = works
    if status == 'done':
        wks = []
        for w in works:
            if w['id'] == id:
                'status' = 'done'
                wks.append(w)

    if status == 'undone':
        wks = []
        for w in tyot:
            if w['id'] == id:
                'status' = 'undone'
                wks.append(w)
                
    return wks
```

Comment: `w['status'] = 'done'`  or `w['status'] = 'undone'`?

Comment: @Rakesh It depends. User can set work status done, or undone. If you write `/works/1/status=done` it should change it done. You know what I mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change

```
'status' = 'done'
```

to

```
w['status'] = 'done'
```

and same modification for the `undone` line.

Answer (score 1):

**If your requirement is only to update the status of the data in the data structure then you could use the below code which is clean.**

```
             for w in works:
                   if w['id'] == id:
                          w['status'] = status
             return works
```